# Adding custom attributes in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make an image which, when clicked, displays some additional information about the image, such as the title. Below is some code I have tried, which seems to work. However, this was just after deciding on my own to try adding a custom attribute "title", rather than reading somewhere that this was the way to do this. So, even though this works for me, I would like to know whether this is good practice, or whether there is a recommended way to do this?

HTML:

```
<img id="test_image" src="images/image1.jpg" title="Test Image">
```

jQuery:

```
$("#test_image").click(function()
{
    alert(this.title);
});
```

Comment: If you want to read a custom attribute, you would have to do something similar like `alert($(this).attr("custom"));` However, I would recommend against this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`title` isn't a custom attribute, it's a standard attribute. It gets displayed in a tooltip when you hover over the element.

You should not create custom attributes. HTML5 has a standard mechanism for user-defined attributes, [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). All attributes beginning with `data-` are reserved for the programmer to use. And jQuery has a method for accessing these, `.data()`.

```js
$("#test_image").click(function()
{
    alert($(this).data('title'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="test_image" src="images/image1.jpg" data-title="Test Image">
```